# Unknown item on unity desktop - is that a widget, can it be removed?

Tags: unity, desktop-background, 14.04

Lately, after installing Ubuntu 14.04 I found a strange item on my desktop. I was only able to see it since it had a layover effect on the white background of my browser. This item was a small (about 50 pixels diameter) circle. Upon closing the browser it stayed on the desktop invisible, however hovering the mouse over it made it slightly visible. It could not be closed nor did it have a right click menu. Eventually it changed to a pin which I clicked and it disappeared.

**EDIT:** I found that it is always there and has a field assigned to it that turns black when I shutdown/logout. My guess is that it is some kind of widget. However, I don't know where to turn it off and to my knowledge I have no widget enabled. I also found it when logging into XFCE4-desktop. There it is easily visible and has a black box to it. Right click does not reveal anything about it.

Does anyone have an idea what that was/is?

Here is an image of the icon, when hovering the mouse over it:

[image]

Comment: Unless you can find a way to reproduce it, this question is likely to be closed. It sounds like a random glitch that will be impossible to track down.

Comment: I am trying to do that - wish I had made a screen-shot or similar at that moment.

Comment: @terdon - I rephrased my question... do you think it is suitable to be reopened?

Comment: Yup, voted to reopen. I have no idea what this is but perhaps someone else will.

Answer (score 2):

I found the responsible program. The indicator "my-weather-indicator" has a widget option. However, that widget does not function correctly and puts the below described pin/circle onto the desktop. Maybe that works correctly, if the widget layer of unity is enabled.

I got rid of the icons now by opening the preferences of the weather indicator and disabling the widget option.